# Use a wrapper class for a list of objects in RequestBody but don't show the property in Swagger UI (Srping MVC)

Tags: spring, jackson, swagger

I have the following method in my `@RestController`:

```
@PostMapping("/api/create")
    public void create(@ApiParam(required = true)
                              @RequestBody MyClass[] my) {
        // ...
    }
```

Now I want to move `MyClass` into a wrapper class, so that I can use `@RequestBody MyClassWrapper wrapped` instead:

```
@PostMapping("/api/create")
    public void create(@ApiParam(required = true)
                              @RequestBody MyClassWrapper wrapped) {
        // ...
    }
```

The wrapper is the following one:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
@Jacksonized
@Schema(name = "MyClassWrapper")
public class MyClassWrapper
{
   @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = MyClass.class))
   private List<MyClass> myClasses;
}
```

I want the swagger ui to display the array of an object of MyClass, like here:

```
[MyClass{
field1 [...]
}]
```

But with my wrapper from above it shows the following:

```
MyClassWrapper{
myClasses   [...]
}
```

How can I get rid of this list and remove the whole wrapper from the swagger ui?

Comment: Not sure if it works for `swagger`, but with `jackson` it could be obtained annotating the `getMyClasses` getter with the `JsonValue` annotation.

Comment: @dariosicily yes! That was the correct hint. The only thing I also needed to add was the `@JsonCreator` annotation to the constructor for a correct deserialization. Thanks!